# Multiple .js files for content script not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am working on a chrome extension that uses content scripts. To make the code a bit more easy to maintain i want to split things up into multiple files. I followed all the instructions everywhere on how to use multiple files for the same match pattern, but nothing seems to be working.

This is my `manifest.json`:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "0.1",

  "description": "This is a test extension",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon-48.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["test.js", "main.js"],
      "matches": ["*://*.netflix.com/*"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]

}
```

Now i have two scripts that i want to use together, `test.js` and `main.js`.

`test.js`:

```
var test = "Hello";
console.log("This is a test");
```

and `main.js`:

```
console.log(test);
```

The variable declared in `test.js` should be global and accessible from the `main.js` script, but when i try it in chrome it says that "test is not defined". Apparently the first script is not even executed, because the `console.log` i added to `test.js` is not showing up in the console at all. I have also made sure that `test.js` is before `main.js` so that it loads in the correct order and i also tried using a library like jquery, but i am just not able to access the variables and functions from the other file inside `main.js`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code is fine. Click the reload icon in extension card on chrome://extensions page and reload the site tab too.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm :)
I don't know what i did wrong before, i mean i reloaded everything too, but all of a sudden it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the addon "Extension Reloader" for Chrome to quickly reload the my extension and the current site and it apparently does not reload the `manifest.json`. Changes to files that are already in the manifest work, but when you add another file into it, it does not run.
So if you use that extension aswell be sure to reload your extension in `chrome://extensions` when changing anything in the manifest.